# Using gganimate and ggplot for a boxplot: Cumulative not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to produce an animation for a simulation model, and I want to show how the distribution of results changes as the simulation runs.

I've seen gganimate used for scatter plots but not for boxplots (or ideally violin plots). Here I've provided a reprex.

When I use `sim_category` (which is a bucket for a certain number of simulation runs) I want the result to be cumulative of all previous runs to show the total distribution.

In this example (and my actual code), `cumulative = TRUE` does not do this. Why is this?

```
library(gganimate)
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)

df = as.data.frame(structure(list(ID = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
                                  value = c(10,15,5,10,7,17,4,12,9,20,6,17),
                                  sim_category = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))))

df$ID <- factor(df$ID, levels = (unique(df$ID))) 
df$sim_category <- factor(df$sim_category, levels = (unique(df$sim_category))) 
ani.options(convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe'))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, value, frame= sim_category, cumulative = TRUE)) + geom_boxplot(position = "identity")

gganimate(p)
```

Comment: I know nothing about the tools you are using nor that code. But I would ask few questions. 1) Is ImageMagick actually installed on your computer and where you say by your path to it. 2) Your "C:" seems to imply you are on Windows. If so, are you using DOS Windows are Window 10 Unix?  3) If DOS Windows, you need to use \ for paths and not /, which are used in unix paths.

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick is install and working, I solved the issue by manually cumulating the rows per category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gganimate`'s cumulative doesn't accumulate the data, it just keeps gif frames in subsequent frames as they appear. To achieve what you want, you have to do the accumulation before building the plot, something along the following lines:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

df <- data_frame(
  ID = factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), levels = 1:2),
  value = c(10,15,5,10,7,17,4,12,9,20,6,17),
  sim_category = factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), levels = 1:3)
) 

p <- df %>%
  pull(sim_category) %>% 
  levels() %>% 
  as.integer() %>%
  map_df(~ df %>% filter(sim_category %in% 1:.x) %>% mutate(sim_category = .x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID, value, frame = factor(sim_category))) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = "identity")


gganimate(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thansk yeedle, I actually got it to work in exactly this way, by manually creating a cumulative distribution in the data frame.